# PHP CLI and Bash - change behaviour of PHP keyword

Tags: bash, command-line, php

Our hosting providers have installed 3 versions of PHP onto our linux box and when I SSH into it the command php points to use/bin/php which is version 5.2, the command php-5.4 points to usr/bin/php-5.4 which is version 5.4 of course.

This isn't a problem when I just need to run a single script that needs a newer version of php, I can just specify php-5.4, however when I try to run the Laravel installer or try to install Laravel using Composer it is throwing errors that are caused by php 5.2 being used.

Is there a way to change where the php keyword points? Or do I need to remove bin/php and rename bin/php-5.4?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can attack this in a variety of ways.

#### Method #1 - alias

You can make an alias, `php=php-5.4`, and then attempt to run your script. Assuming that it relies on the current shells ability to locate how to run things, then it should pickup the alias for `php` instead of the `php` that's located under `/usr/bin`.

#### Method #2 - $PATH

You can override the precendence of where shells locate executables by manipulating the `$PATH` environment variable. Simply add the location of some other directory to the front of the `$PATH`.

```
export PATH=/path/to/newdir:$PATH
```

Now put a shell script or link in this directory named `php`. Here's the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

php-5.4 $*
```

Here's the link:

```
$ cd /path/to/newdir
$ ln -s /usr/bin/php-5.4 php
```

Comment: Method 2 Worked perfectly, composer was able to install Laravel first try, php -v confirms version 5.4 is being executed.